# ¿Por qué se hacen cambios en la base de datos pero no en la vista de la aplicación?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, godaddy

Tengo un aplicativo el cual el título es configurable realizado en Laravel utilizando Ajax para las consultas; así que cuando cambio el título éste debe verse refleado en la pantalla principal.
El título sí se guarda en la base de datos pero al momento de refrescar la pantalla principal se ve el anterior.
El problema es que esto sucede con todo. Guarda en la base de datos pero no se ven reflejados los cambios
He revisado si el tema es de CSRF que, aveces no deja realizar consultas Ajax, sin embargo no es éste el problema. 
Cabe mencionar que localmente funciona a la perfección pero en GoDaddy, donde tengo alojada mi página es donde falla (antes todo funcionaba de maravilla)
Si debo incluir algún código o corregir mi pregunta, hacermelo saber. Gracias

Comment: ¿La consola muestra algo?

Comment: Hola, no estoy en un servidor compartido, no puedo revisar consola. Gracias por responder :)

Comment: Hablo de la consola de tu navegador

Answer (score 0):

Deberías añadir algo de código, pero si se refleja en BBDD quiere decir que si que llega al backend, con lo que me quedaría con algún error en el JS, no tiene porque ser el código que hace referencia al comportamiento sino previo o posterior que haga que no se ejecute bien. Lo mejor es ilustrarlo con tu código.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que todo localmente funciona, en producción se ve la pagina recién subida ... pero al hacer cambios, ya sea en la bd o en algún archivo (subido al host) ya no refleja cambios He visto lo de config:clear, view:clear eliminar views de storage, y realmente nada funciona

Comment: y ¿en la consola del navegador se muestra algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces el cambio en la base de datos, has probado entrando desde otra pc? o en modo incognito?

Por ejemplo pasa cuando haces ediciones css desde la pagina en produccion, aveces queda grabado en cache algo y simplemente no lo edita sino hasta cerrar y abrir de nuevo etc.. no se que si ese sea tu caso pero prueba a ver.

Ademas has otro intento, ve a una pagina de host gratuito y prueba tu sistema alli, GoDaddy al igual que muchos hosting tienen sus pequeñas configuraciones que hacen que por un pequeño error de codigo el cual en localhost si sirve, hace que en la pagina no lo haga